# Java as a frontend to dd to copy iso to usb

Tags: java, user-interface, frontend, iso, dd

I'm trying to write a frontend to dd with java. specifically to flash an iso image over to a usbdrive. basically ask the user for the correct /dev path, then asking user for the path to the iso, then feeding everything into dd, and showing feedback when dd finishes. -eg "Iso copy done." or "Iso copy Failed"

I am new to programming and java, and I'm not sure exactly what packages I need to feed input to a unix utility such as dd in java. As for the gui, it looks like I need java.awt and javax.swing.

Is there anything I'm missing? could I get some pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, and it's associated classes like Process, and Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials out there using Swing. But most of the older samples don't create the GUI in the event-dispatch thread. To start with Swing correct, start from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/about.html.

If you are interested in JavaFX the above link might also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, consider reading about ProcessBuilder class which allows you to write terminal commands that will run. For the GUI you have awt, swing and javafx with javafx providing far more nicer UI controls. I suggest you think of how you can track the progress of the dd process as it is very annoying when using it and you dont know far the process has gone. the progressbar and progress indicator will be nice to do that. Let's know how far it goes i will love to see the outcome of it. will be glad to help(euoles@yahoo.com)